# Simple haskell lens from tutorial violates lens law

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I'm reading this tutorial:

http://blog.jakubarnold.cz/2014/08/06/lens-tutorial-stab-traversal-part-2.html

and my code looks like this:

```
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Traversable
import Control.Lens

data User = User String [Post] deriving Show
data Post = Post String deriving Show

posts :: Lens' User [Post]
posts f (User n p) = fmap (User n) (f p)

users :: [User]
users = [User "john" [Post "hello", Post "world"], User "bob" [Post "foobar"]]

tp :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => ([Post] -> f [Post]) -> t User -> f (t User)
tp = traverse . posts
```

Now following the blog post, here are some common lens computations:

```
*Main> view tp users
[Post "hello",Post "world",Post "foobar"]

*Main> set tp [Post "x",Post "y"] users
[User "john" [Post "x",Post "y"],User "bob" [Post "x",Post "y"]]

*Main> view tp (set tp [Post "x",Post "y"] users)
[Post "x",Post "y",Post "x",Post "y"]
```

The last evaluation has left me confused. Isn't the following lens law supposed to hold?

```
view l (set l v s) = v
```

(The law is taken from http://artyom.me/lens-over-tea-2.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a lens law, and `tp` is a traversal, so it doesn't have to abide by this law.

Strictly speaking, `view` shouldn't work with traversals at all (it works anyway, but it does so by combining the gathered results monoidally).

Comment: So if I understand what you're saying, if `a` and `b` are lenses then so is `a . b`. But `traverse . a` is no longer a lens but a traversal. Is there any other way traversals are produced by composition? If `c` and `d` are traversals, is `c . d` also a traversal?

Comment: @danpomaro Yep. `lens + lens` = lens; `lens + traversal` = `traversal + lens` = `traversal + traversal` = traversal.

Comment: @danpomaro The [lens documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) includes a diagram with details; compose things from two blue boxes, and what you get is something from any blue box that they both have a path to.